# How to perform range searches on Height in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

How to represent Height and HeightRange in Elasticsearch, so that its easier to do range searches

```
Height.java: int feet, int inches;
HeightRange.java: Height from, Height to
```

I want to search for users who fall in a certain range (say 5ft - 6ft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your issue well, you ay use a range query as follows. I did a local test as follows, where I ingested the following data:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "height-index-array",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "OfCHdXUB1QlsTOLdRJgd",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "user" : "user1",
      "height" : {
        "feet" : 5,
        "inch" : 8
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "height-index-array",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "CfCJdXUB1QlsTOLdEZxS",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "user" : "user2",
      "height" : {
        "feet" : 7,
        "inch" : 9
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "height-index-array",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "CvCJdXUB1QlsTOLdEpx5",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "user" : "user3",
      "height" : {
        "feet" : 5,
        "inch" : 6
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "height-index-array",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "C_CJdXUB1QlsTOLdE5yk",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "user" : "user4",
      "height" : {
        "feet" : 5,
        "inch" : 8
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "height-index-array",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "T_CJdXUB1QlsTOLdFZwx",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "user" : "user5",
      "height" : {
        "feet" : 2,
        "inch" : 3
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The query which I used to query the the `height` in `feet` between 5 and 6:

```
"query": {
    "range": {
    "height.feet": {
        "gte": 5,
        "lte": 6
    }
    }
}
```

The `gte` is equivalent to `greater than or equal to` and the `lte` is equivalent to `less than or equal to`.

The results are:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
    "value" : 3,
    "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
    {
        "_index" : "height-index-array",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "OfCHdXUB1QlsTOLdRJgd",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
        "user" : "user1",
        "height" : {
            "feet" : 5,
            "inch" : 8
        }
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "height-index-array",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "CvCJdXUB1QlsTOLdEpx5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
        "user" : "user3",
        "height" : {
            "feet" : 5,
            "inch" : 6
        }
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "height-index-array",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "C_CJdXUB1QlsTOLdE5yk",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
        "user" : "user4",
        "height" : {
            "feet" : 5,
            "inch" : 8
        }
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

Let me know if you have any issues, I will be glad to help :)

As per your request, if you need to combine both metrics, you may use a bool query:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
    "must": [
        {
        "range": {
            "height.feet": {
            "gte": 5,
            "lte": 6
            }
        }
        },{
        "range": {
            "height.inch": {
            "gte": 6,
            "lte": 8
            }
        }
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

The response:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "height-index-array",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "OfCHdXUB1QlsTOLdRJgd",
    "_score" : 2.0,
    "_source" : {
      "user" : "user1",
      "height" : {
        "feet" : 5,
        "inch" : 8
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "height-index-array",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "CvCJdXUB1QlsTOLdEpx5",
    "_score" : 2.0,
    "_source" : {
      "user" : "user3",
      "height" : {
        "feet" : 5,
        "inch" : 6
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "height-index-array",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "C_CJdXUB1QlsTOLdE5yk",
    "_score" : 2.0,
    "_source" : {
      "user" : "user4",
      "height" : {
        "feet" : 5,
        "inch" : 8
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Links:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: how would you combine the inch also as part of the search query

Comment: @user352290 you can use bool query, to combine multiple range queries